# Powershell Select-XML - Trouble with XPath as absolute Path

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath, gpo

Hello powershell fellows,

i have another issue with powershell and xml.

**What i try to do:**
I have an XML File (more accurately, it is a xml export of a AD GPO). This XML looks very similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
-<GPO xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    -<Identifier>
        <Identifier xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types"></Identifier>
        <Domain xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">Testdomain.local</Domain>
    </Identifier>
    <Name>ExampleName</Name>
    <IncludeComments>true</IncludeComments>
    <CreatedTime>2022-07-26T11:12:25</CreatedTime>
    <ModifiedTime>2022-07-26T11:56:44</ModifiedTime>
    <ReadTime>2022-07-26T11:56:52.7975554Z</ReadTime>
    -<Computer>
        <VersionDirectory>1</VersionDirectory>
        <VersionSysvol>1</VersionSysvol>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        -<ExtensionData>
            -<Extension xsi:type="q1:SecuritySettings" xmlns:q1="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings/Security">
                -<q1:SecurityOptions>
                    <q1:KeyName>TestKeyName</q1:KeyName>
                    <q1:SettingNumber>5</q1:SettingNumber>
                    -<q1:Display>
                        <q1:Name>TestName</q1:Name>
                        <q1:Units/>
                        <q1:DisplayString>TestValue</q1:DisplayString>
                    </q1:Display>
                </q1:SecurityOptions>
         ...
```

Now i want to address these xml nodes with Select-XML cmdlet. I need to use a absolute Xpath Path. Lets say i want to get the value of "SecurityOptions/Display/Name".

I tried something like this:

```
$namespace = @{ns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings";xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";q1="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings/Security"}

$xpath = '/q1:SecurityOptions/q1:Display/q1:Name'
$result = (Select-Xml -Path "C:\examplepath\example.xml" -XPath $xpath -Namespace $namespace).Node.InnerText
```

But this gets me no value at all :/

**What works:**

On the other hand, when i do not use an absolute path like:

```
$xpath = '//q1:Name'
$result = (Select-Xml -Path "C:\examplepath\example.xml" -XPath $xpath -Namespace $namespace).Node.InnerText
```

It gives me some result. But i want to address the XML Nodes with an absolute path not only with a relative path.

Maybe anyone can tell me what i am doing wrong here. :)

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is as simple as adding a missing `/`. Not sure why you have to use an absolute path, but in your relative path, your expression `//q1:Name` starts with `//` which covers all descendants nodes of the root with that name. In your absolute path expression `/q1:SecurityOptions...` you start with `/`, which looks only for direct child elements of the root by that name. But the `/q1:SecurityOptions`element is burred several layers down the tree.

So long story short, changing your xpath expression to

```
'//q1:SecurityOptions/q1:Display/q1:Name'
```

should work.

Comment: Thank you very much for this simple yet effective solution. This worked perfectly and was absolutly eye opening for me on how xpath works.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply using PowerShell's Dot notation?

```
$Xml = [Xml]@'
<GPO xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Identifier>
        <Identifier xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types"></Identifier>
        <Domain xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">Testdomain.local</Domain>
    </Identifier>
    <Name>ExampleName</Name>
    <IncludeComments>true</IncludeComments>
    <CreatedTime>2022-07-26T11:12:25</CreatedTime>
    <ModifiedTime>2022-07-26T11:56:44</ModifiedTime>
    <ReadTime>2022-07-26T11:56:52.7975554Z</ReadTime>
    <Computer>
        <VersionDirectory>1</VersionDirectory>
        <VersionSysvol>1</VersionSysvol>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        <ExtensionData>
            <Extension xsi:type="q1:SecuritySettings" xmlns:q1="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings/Security">
                <q1:SecurityOptions>
                    <q1:KeyName>TestKeyName</q1:KeyName>
                    <q1:SettingNumber>5</q1:SettingNumber>
                    <q1:Display>
                        <q1:Name>TestName</q1:Name>
                        <q1:Units/>
                        <q1:DisplayString>TestValue</q1:DisplayString>
                    </q1:Display>
                </q1:SecurityOptions>
            </Extension>
        </ExtensionData>
    </Computer>
</GPO>
'@
```

```
$Xml.GPO.Computer.ExtensionData.Extension.SecurityOptions.Display.Name
TestName
```

**Note:** text (leaf) nodes are returned as strings by the PowerShell accelerated `[Xml]` parser. This implementation is essential incorrect and noted here: [`#16878` Decorate dot selected Xml strings (leaves) with XmlElement methods](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16878). This behavior might cause difficulties if you e.g. want to change the node. To ensure that the (leaf) node you select is always an `XmlElement`, you might do something like:

```
$NameTable = @{
    ns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings"
    xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    q1="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings/Security"
}
$NameSpace = [Xml.XmlNamespaceManager]$Xml.NameTable
$NameTable.Keys.ForEach{ $NameSpace.AddNamespace($_, $NameTable[$_]) }

$Extension = $Xml.GPO.Computer.ExtensionData.Extension
$NameNode = $Extension.SecurityOptions.Display.SelectSingleNode('q1:Name', $NameSpace)
$NameNode.InnerText = 'NewValue'
```

```
[System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Parse($Xml.GPO.Computer.ExtensionData.Extension.OuterXml).ToString()

<Extension xsi:type="q1:SecuritySettings" xmlns:q1="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings/Security" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings">
  <q1:SecurityOptions>
    <q1:KeyName>TestKeyName</q1:KeyName>
    <q1:SettingNumber>5</q1:SettingNumber>
    <q1:Display>
      <q1:Name>NewValue</q1:Name>
      <q1:Units />
      <q1:DisplayString>TestValue</q1:DisplayString>
    </q1:Display>
  </q1:SecurityOptions>
</Extension>
```

Comment: Thank you @iRon for your answer. My whole script is now based on the Dot notation. Unfortunatly the dot notation has, for various reasons, in my szenario limitations. So i looked around for an alternative to the dot notation and came up with the Select-XML.
So i need advice for Select-XML

Comment: Not sure with limitations you refer to, AFAIK they are just different technics with different approaches (which includes iteration and mixing with XPath). Anyways, taking this gotha ([`#16878` Decorate dot selected Xml strings (leaves) with XmlElement methods](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16878)) in account, I have updated my answer to show that the **dot notation** technic is quiet unlimited as wel.